# Visual Studio C compiler custom floating point precision

Tags: visual-studio, floating-point, precision

I have a program running on an archaic Infineon C166 processor, compiled with Keil C166. The Keil floating point arithmetic library has an intricacy where it reduces the single-precision float comparison to 21 bits of mantissa precision instead of the 24 bits available.

http://www.keil.com/support/docs/3627.htm

When cross-compiling the code to Visual Studio, this effect became apparent as two float values 0.9 plus and minus epsilon (0x3F666666 "<" 0x3F666667) were considered equal on the Keil code, whereas the Visual Studio correctly considers one smaller than the other.

In order to try and have the similar effect on the cross-compiled code without altering "<" operators everywhere (the embedded code is a "golden reference"), is there a way to intercept/swap out floating point operators in Visual Studio (disabling intrinsics and linking a custom-defined set of FP functions) instead?